# The type org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver is not accessible

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, java-10

I am getting the error like "The type org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver is not accessible" for almost all the classes I am using in Selenium.

It was working fine till I was using Java 8 but when I upgraded to Java 10 I am getting errors like this.

See the screenshot of the project below:

[image]

**Edit 1:**

Selenium-server jar file also contains all the webdriver code as well. See the below image. It has the ChromeDriver class in the same package which I have imported in the above class. The same combination is working fine If I am using either Java 8 (again see the below screenshot)or an older version of eclipse say neon.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is your Chromedriver jar?

Comment: ChromeDriver is class in Selenium-server-standalone jar file included in referenced libraries

Comment: No, chromedriver is a separate download. You are also using the server standalone which is Selenium grid. Your code doesn't look like you are intending to use grid, so you need to download and use a different jar. You should probably start with a basic tutorial for setting up Selenium and Java. You are missing a lot of jar files and the Chrome driver.

Comment: Selenium-server jar file also contains all the webdriver code as well. I have added a screenshot in the question itself.

Also, the same combination  is working fine If I am using either Java 8 or an older version of eclipse say neon. See the screenshot attached

Comment: @SaurabhDhingra are you using JPMS or by any chance while upgrading to Java-10, have you checked your eclipse configuration if they are relying on the modulepath and your dependency(the selenium jar) might not be readable or present there to be read?

Comment: I had the same issue, and I just deleted the module info class, then the error is gone.

Answer (score 16):

To avoid such error, You should change java compiler to early version 1.7 or 1.7 from configuring build path.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I too got the same error, There would be a file named module-info.java in src folder. Just comment on all lines in it and the error is gone. I am not sure how, but it works.

Comment: I'm brand new to selenium and this solved it for me

Answer (score 3):

When configuring build path, make sure the external jars are added under classpath folder not under any other folder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ropKR.png)

Download Jars from following link:
https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=4.0/

Answer (score 0):

Download selenium Client and Webdriver jar form the below link:

https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: Selenium-server standalone also has Selenium Webdriver code. It is one jar file which has all other jar files combined. I have downloaded from the same link. The issue is with either Java 10 or with Eclipse photon which I am not able to resolve :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue today with eclipse photon. In the process of fixing the issue, i removed selenium standalone jar and issue was resolved. I could see you added selenium standalone jar to your project. Remove that and try again. Hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the latest version of selenium.server.standalone.jar and instal and add to build path any previous version. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had added the jars file in modulepath. Make sure you are adding them in classpath while choosing to add external jars.

Answer (score 0):

Years later I got this gem with selenium-java-3.141.59 turns out they've done some jar shuffling and I needed to add "requires okio;" to module-info.java

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem too. Just create a new project without creating a module package. Now it runs without errors.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows & Linux users..  Just go on this link and download jar files (even on Linux because no matter if Linux doesn't understand .jar but eclipse does while uploading in build path)

https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/4.0/selenium-java-4.0.0-alpha-1.zip

remove all other jars and just keep above jars from lib and other folders in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Remove module-info.java from src folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i am facing the same problem ... org.openqa.selenium is not accessible....

i tried to delete module.java.... the problem is still alive.

so i am trying to correct this problem...

Step 1: go to the project right click and select properties
step 2: There select Add Library -- > add  JRE System Library -- > Execution Environment ---> select Latest version --> Apply

the problem resolved automatically

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also got same issue. I removed selenium jar from modulePath and added to classpath and problem resolved.